# Adding multiple stages in a step in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to get a pipeline that would have 2 steps running in parallel where the YAML looks like:

```
      steps:
        - step: Step1
          stages:
            - stage: Build
              steps:
                - *build_a
                - *build_b
                - *build_c
            - stage: Sniff
              steps:
                - *sniff
            - stage: Accept
              steps:
                - *regress
                - *test_suite_a
        - *slow_build_that_can_run_in_parallel_to_all_the_above
```

But Jenkins just passes with the above without running anything. So, I also tried putting everything above in a stage and the `slow_build_*` ran but `Step1` failed to run since it tried to submit the whole step as a batch instead of breaking it into stages.

Is it possible in Jenkins to get multiple stages inside of a step? Or am I doing this wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No you can't have `stages` in a `step`

This is from the [Pipeline syntax doc](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/).

- Stages: *Only once, inside the `pipeline` block*
- Stage: *Inside the `stages` section*
- **Steps**: *Inside each `stage` block*

Answer (score 11):

Here's what you can do:

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        stage('This is a Level 1 Stage') {
            stages {
                stage(This is a level 2 stage') { steps{...} }
                stage(This is a level 2 stage') { steps{...} }
                stage(This is a level 2 stage') { steps{...} }
            }
        }
        stage('This is a Level 1 Stage') {
            stages {
                stage(This is a level 2 stage') { steps{...} }
                stage(This is a level 2 stage') { steps{...} }
                stage(This is a level 2 stage') { steps{...} }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since Jenkins are now allowing nested stages, you can put a stages into a stage to make nested level of stages.